# socks4 with asynchronous boost::asio

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio, http-proxy, socks

I'm trying to hack into an existing appilication a socks4 client. The program uses asynchronous boost::asio.

So i've worked out so far that i need to negotiate with the socks4 server first:

```
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint socks_proxy{boost::asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1"),1080};
    if( socks_proxy.protocol() != boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4() )
    {
       throw boost::system::system_error(
         boost::asio::error::address_family_not_supported);
    }
    
    ....
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket* m_socket;
    
    // negotiate with the socks server
    // m_endpoint is an item in std::queue<boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp>> m_endpoints
    boost::asio::ip::address_v4::bytes_type address_ = m_endpoint.address().to_v4().to_bytes();
    unsigned short port = m_endpoint.port();
    unsigned char port_high_byte_ = (port >> 8) & 0xff;
    unsigned char port_low_byte_ = port & 0xff;
    boost::array<boost::asio::const_buffer, 7> send_buffer =
    {
      {
        boost::asio::buffer(&SOCKS_VERSION, 1), // const unsigned char SOCKS_VERSION = 0x04;
        boost::asio::buffer(&SOCKS_CONNECT, 1), // const unsigned char SOCKS_VERSION = 0x04;
        boost::asio::buffer(&port_high_byte_, 1),
        boost::asio::buffer(&port_low_byte_, 1),
        boost::asio::buffer(address_),
        boost::asio::buffer("userid"),
        boost::asio::buffer(&null_byte_, 1).    // unsigned char null_byte_ = 0;
      }
    };
    // initiate socks
    boost::asio::write( m_socket, send_buffer );
    // check it worked
    unsigned char status_;
    boost::array<boost::asio::mutable_buffer, 5> reply_buffer =
    {
      {
        boost::asio::buffer(&null_byte_, 1),
        boost::asio::buffer(&status_, 1),
        boost::asio::buffer(&port_high_byte_, 1),
        boost::asio::buffer(&port_low_byte_, 1),
        boost::asio::buffer(address_)
      }
    };
    boost::asio::read( m_socket, reply_buffer );
    
    if( ! ( null_byte_ == 0 && status_ == 0x5a ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Proxy connection failed.\n";
    }
```

However, the exist application code bascially does:

```
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket* m_socket;
    
    m_nonsecuresocket = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(m_io_service);
    m_socket = m_nonsecuresocket.get();
    
    m_socket->async_connect(m_endpoint,
        m_io_strand.wrap(boost::bind(&CLASS::connect_handler, this, _1)));
```

so that even if i could get it to compile, the async_connect would disconnect the socket anyway.

How can i integrate the socks4 client code into the `async_connect()`?

Comment: You need to replace `async_connect` with your own connection code. Did you try? If you are stuck doing that, please post a question about what you are stuck with. Now you're just showing code that isn't really relevant.

Comment: Also, as written there's a bug because `"userid"` includes the NUL terminator already

Comment: thanks @sehe; yes, the `"userid"` was the ultimate issue of why i couldn't get this to work - thanks!

Comment: wow. That's some coincidence. It **does** highlight the value of having concrete code, which, funnily was enough to diagnose the issue. I did in fact start out with that and scratching my head why it didn't work, so you can count the amount of time it took for me to spot it from the comment timestamps. Only after that I started thinking about answering the more broad "how to integrate" question, for which you can see my answer.

Comment: In light of the value to future visitors I'd appreciate a vote/accept on the answer as well, even though it wasn't essential to your solution, perhaps

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, I think your question requires a lot more focus. However, since this is actually a useful question and it might be good to have an example, I went ahead and implemented a `socks4::async_proxy_connect` operation:

```
tcp::socket sock{io};
tcp::endpoint
    target({}, 80),  // connect to localhost:http
    proxy{{}, 1080}; // via SOCKS4 proxy on localhost:1080

socks4::async_proxy_connect(sock, target, proxy, handler);

// continue using sock
```

Loose ends:

- <strike>synchronous version is not implemented yet (but should be a lot simpler)</strike> **added**
- does not include address resolution (just as your question). Integrating that would require quite a bit of the groundwork in `boost::asio::async_connect` that takes a resolver query. Sadly, that doesn't seen well factored for reuse.

### Listing

- File `socks4.hpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>

   namespace socks4 { // threw in the kitchen sink for error codes
   #ifdef STANDALONE_ASIO
       using std::error_category;
       using std::error_code;
       using std::error_condition;
       using std::system_error;
   #else
       namespace asio = boost::asio;
       using boost::system::error_category;
       using boost::system::error_code;
       using boost::system::error_condition;
       using boost::system::system_error;
   #endif

       enum class result_code {
           ok                 = 0,
           invalid_version    = 1,
           rejected_or_failed = 3,
           need_identd        = 4,
           unconirmed_userid  = 5,
           //
           failed = 99,
       };

       auto const& get_result_category() {
         struct impl : error_category {
           const char* name() const noexcept override { return "result_code"; }
           std::string message(int ev) const override {
             switch (static_cast<result_code>(ev)) {
             case result_code::ok:                 return "Success";
             case result_code::invalid_version:    return "SOCKS4 invalid reply version";
             case result_code::rejected_or_failed: return "SOCKS4 rejected or failed";
             case result_code::need_identd:        return "SOCKS4 unreachable (client not running identd)";
             case result_code::unconirmed_userid:  return "SOCKS4 identd could not confirm user ID";
             case result_code::failed:             return "SOCKS4 general unexpected failure";
             default: return "unknown error";
             }
           }
           error_condition
           default_error_condition(int ev) const noexcept override {
               return error_condition{ev, *this};
           }
           bool equivalent(int ev, error_condition const& condition)
               const noexcept override {
               return condition.value() == ev && &condition.category() == this;
           }
           bool equivalent(error_code const& error,
                           int ev) const noexcept override {
               return error.value() == ev && &error.category() == this;
           }
         } const static instance;
         return instance;
       }

       error_code make_error_code(result_code se) {
           return error_code{
               static_cast<std::underlying_type<result_code>::type>(se),
               get_result_category()};
       }
   } // namespace socks4

   template <>
   struct boost::system::is_error_code_enum<socks4::result_code>
       : std::true_type {};

   namespace socks4 {
       using namespace std::placeholders;

       template <typename Endpoint> struct core_t {
           Endpoint _target;
           Endpoint _proxy;

           core_t(Endpoint target, Endpoint proxy)
               : _target(target)
               , _proxy(proxy) {}

   #pragma pack(push)
   #pragma pack(1)
           using ipv4_octets = boost::asio::ip::address_v4::bytes_type;
           using net_short   = boost::endian::big_uint16_t;

           struct alignas(void*) Req {
               uint8_t     version = 0x04;
               uint8_t     cmd     = 0x01;
               net_short   port;
               ipv4_octets address;
           } _request{0x04, 0x01, _target.port(),
                      _target.address().to_v4().to_bytes()};

           struct alignas(void*) Res {
               uint8_t     reply_version;
               uint8_t     status;
               net_short   port;
               ipv4_octets address;
           } _response;
   #pragma pack(pop)

           using const_buffer   = boost::asio::const_buffer;
           using mutable_buffer = boost::asio::mutable_buffer;

           auto request_buffers(char const* szUserId) const {
               return std::array<const_buffer, 2>{
                   boost::asio::buffer(&_request, sizeof(_request)),
                   boost::asio::buffer(szUserId, strlen(szUserId) + 1)};
           }

           auto response_buffers() {
               return boost::asio::buffer(&_response, sizeof(_response));
           }

           error_code get_result(error_code ec = {}) const {
               if (ec)
                   return ec;
               if (_response.reply_version != 0)
                   return result_code::invalid_version;

               switch (_response.status) {
                 case 0x5a: return result_code::ok; // Request grantd
                 case 0x5B: return result_code::rejected_or_failed;
                 case 0x5C: return result_code::need_identd;
                 case 0x5D: return result_code::unconirmed_userid;
               }

               return result_code::failed;
           }
       };

       template <typename Socket, typename Completion>
       struct async_proxy_connect_op {
           using Endpoint      = typename Socket::protocol_type::endpoint;
           using executor_type = typename Socket::executor_type;
           auto get_executor() { return _socket.get_executor(); }

         private:
           core_t<Endpoint> _core;
           Socket&          _socket;
           std::string      _userId;
           Completion       _handler;

         public:
           async_proxy_connect_op(Completion handler, Socket& s, Endpoint target,
                                  Endpoint proxy, std::string user_id = {})
               : _core(target, proxy)
               , _socket(s)
               , _userId(std::move(user_id))
               , _handler(std::move(handler)) {}

           using Self = std::unique_ptr<async_proxy_connect_op>;
           void init(Self&& self) { operator()(self, INIT{}); }

         private:
           // states
           struct INIT{};
           struct CONNECT{};
           struct SENT{};
           struct ONRESPONSE{};

           struct Binder {
               Self _self;
               template <typename... Args>
               decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) {
                   return (*_self)(_self, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
               }
           };

           void operator()(Self& self, INIT) {
               _socket.async_connect(_core._proxy,
                  std::bind(Binder{std::move(self)}, CONNECT{}, _1));
           }

           void operator()(Self& self, CONNECT, error_code ec) {
               if (ec) return _handler(ec);
               boost::asio::async_write(
                   _socket,
                   _core.request_buffers(_userId.c_str()),
                   std::bind(Binder{std::move(self)}, SENT{}, _1, _2));
           }

           void operator()(Self& self, SENT, error_code ec, size_t xfer) {
               if (ec) return _handler(ec);
               auto buf = _core.response_buffers();
               boost::asio::async_read(
                   _socket, buf, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(buffer_size(buf)),
                   std::bind(Binder{std::move(self)}, ONRESPONSE{}, _1, _2));
           }

           void operator()(Self& self, ONRESPONSE, error_code ec, size_t xfer) {
               _handler(_core.get_result(ec));
           }
       };

       template <typename Socket,
                 typename Endpoint = typename Socket::protocol_type::endpoint>
       error_code proxy_connect(Socket& s, Endpoint ep, Endpoint proxy,
                                std::string const& user_id, error_code& ec) {
           core_t<Endpoint> core(ep, proxy);
           ec.clear();

           s.connect(core._proxy, ec);

           if (!ec)
               boost::asio::write(s, core.request_buffers(user_id.c_str()),
                                  ec);
           auto buf = core.response_buffers();
           if (!ec)
               boost::asio::read(s, core.response_buffers(),
                                 boost::asio::transfer_exactly(buffer_size(buf)), ec);

           return ec = core.get_result(ec);
       }

       template <typename Socket,
                 typename Endpoint = typename Socket::protocol_type::endpoint>
       void proxy_connect(Socket& s, Endpoint ep, Endpoint proxy,
                          std::string const& user_id = "") {
           error_code ec;
           if (proxy_connect(s, ep, proxy, user_id, ec))
               throw system_error(ec);
       }

       template <typename Socket, typename Token,
                 typename Endpoint = typename Socket::protocol_type::endpoint>
       auto async_proxy_connect(Socket& s, Endpoint ep, Endpoint proxy,
                          std::string user_id, Token&& token) {
           using Result = asio::async_result<std::decay_t<Token>, void(error_code)>;
           using Completion = typename Result::completion_handler_type;

           Completion completion(std::forward<Token>(token));
           Result     result(completion);

           using Op = async_proxy_connect_op<Socket, Completion>;
           // make an owning self ptr, to serve a unique async chain
           auto self =
               std::make_unique<Op>(completion, s, ep, proxy, std::move(user_id));
           self->init(std::move(self));
           return result.get();
       }

       template <typename Socket, typename Token,
                 typename Endpoint = typename Socket::protocol_type::endpoint>
       auto async_proxy_connect(Socket& s, Endpoint ep, Endpoint proxy, Token&& token) {
           return async_proxy_connect<Socket, Token, Endpoint>(
               s, ep, proxy, "", std::forward<Token>(token));
       }
   } // namespace socks4
  ```

### Demo

- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   #include "socks4.hpp"

   #include <boost/beast.hpp>
   #include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
   #include <iostream>

   int main(int argc, char**) {
       bool synchronous = argc > 1;

       using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
       boost::asio::thread_pool ctx(1); // just one thread will do

       tcp::socket sock{ctx};
       tcp::endpoint target(
           boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("173.203.57.63"), 80),
           proxy{{}, 1080};

       try {
           if (synchronous) {
               std::cerr << "Using synchronous interface" << std::endl;
               socks4::proxy_connect(sock, target,
                                     proxy); // throws system_error if failed
           } else {
               std::cerr << "Using asynchronous interface" << std::endl;
               // using the async interface (still emulating synchronous by using
               // future for brevity of this demo)
               auto fut = socks4::async_proxy_connect(sock, target, proxy,
                                                      boost::asio::use_future);

               fut.get(); // throws system_error if failed
           }

           // Now do a request using beast
           namespace beast = boost::beast;
           namespace http  = beast::http;

           {
               http::request<http::empty_body> req(http::verb::get, "/", 11);
               req.set(http::field::host, "coliru.stacked-crooked.com");
               req.set(http::field::connection, "close");
               std::cout << "-------\nRequest: " << req << "\n-------\n";
               http::write(sock, req);
           }

           {
               http::response<http::string_body> res;
               beast::flat_buffer                buf;

               http::read(sock, buf, res);
               std::cout << "\n-------\nResponse: " << res << "\n";
           }
       } catch(socks4::system_error const& se) {
           std::cerr << "Error: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
       }

       ctx.join();
   }
  ```

### Output

```
Using asynchronous interface
-------
Request: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: coliru.stacked-crooked.com
Connection: close


-------

-------
Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 8616
Server: WEBrick/1.4.2 (Ruby/2.5.1/2018-03-29) OpenSSL/1.0.2g
Date: Thu, 29 Apr 2021 19:05:03 GMT
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Coliru</title>
```

(rest of response omitted)

Comment: [Added](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67320567/revisions) the synchronous version for good measure, using code sharing between the sync/async versions.

Comment: Added [socks5.hpp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69781530/85371) today. Decided to publish the code for socks4.hpp/socks5.hpp on github: https://github.com/sehe/asio-socks45-client