# Is there a native support for proxy connection via socks5 for boost::asio?

Tags: c++, proxy, boost-asio, http-proxy, socks

I'm using boost::asio to handle network communication between my program and remote server. To establish a connection with a server I do the following sequence of operations:

```
namespace ba = boost::asio;
boost::shared_ptr<ba::ssl::context> ssl_ctx;
boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context> ios;  // initialized
boost::shared_ptr<ba::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>> ssl_socket;

ssl_ctx.reset(new ba::ssl::context(boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method::sslv23));
ssl_ctx->set_verify_mode(ba::ssl::verify_peer);
ssl_ctx->add_certificate_authority(ba::buffer(certs.data(), certs.size()));

ssl_socket.reset(new ba::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>(*ios, *ssl_ctx));

auto& socket = ssl_socket->next_layer();

ba::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator ep_iter; // target server
std::future<tcp::resolver::iterator> conn_result = boost::asio::async_connect(socket, ep_iter, boost::asio::use_future);
auto status = conn_result.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(wait_connection_timeout_sec));
if (status == std::future_status::timeout) {
    socket.cancel();
    throw std::runtime_error("wait on server connection is timed out");
}

conn_result.get(); // if the operation failed, then conn_result.get() will throw an error
if (!socket.is_open()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("can't open socket");
}

socket.set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));

ssl_socket->handshake(ba::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>::handshake_type::client);
```

This code works perfect. After connection I use standard methods to write/read with ssl_socket.

Now I need to establish connection to my server via proxy server using socks5 protocol.
Didn't find a solution in the boost manual. Is there a native socks5 proxy support? What should I add to my code sequence so as to get ssl_socket connected to my server via proxy server?

Comment: Not really. But I made a SOCKS4 implementation recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67309087/socks4-with-asynchronous-boostasio/67320567#67320567 It should probably help you get started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead with the finger exercise and implemented `socks5.hpp` like I did before for socks4: [socks4 with asynchronous boost::asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67309087/socks4-with-asynchronous-boostasio/67320567#67320567)

Without further ado:

```
tcp::resolver::query target("example.com", "443");

std::future<void> conn_result = socks5::async_proxy_connect(
    socket, target, tcp::endpoint{{}, 1080}, ba::use_future);
```

Or, of course, just synchronously:

```
socks5::proxy_connect(socket, target, tcp::endpoint{{}, 1080});
```

### Live Demo

- File `socks5.hpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>

   namespace socks5 { // threw in the kitchen sink for error codes
   #ifdef STANDALONE_ASIO
       using std::error_category;
       using std::error_code;
       using std::error_condition;
       using std::system_error;
   #else
       namespace asio = boost::asio;
       using boost::system::error_category;
       using boost::system::error_code;
       using boost::system::error_condition;
       using boost::system::system_error;
   #endif

       enum class result_code {
           ok                         = 0,
           invalid_version            = 1,
           disallowed                 = 2,
           auth_method_rejected       = 3,
           network_unreachable        = 4,
           host_unreachable           = 5,
           connection_refused         = 6,
           ttl_expired                = 7,
           command_not_supported      = 8,
           address_type_not_supported = 9,
           //
           failed = 99,
       };

       auto const& get_result_category() {
         struct impl : error_category {
           const char* name() const noexcept override { return "result_code"; }
           std::string message(int ev) const override {
             switch (static_cast<result_code>(ev)) {
             case result_code::ok:                         return "Success";
             case result_code::invalid_version:            return "SOCKS5 invalid reply version";
             case result_code::disallowed:                 return "SOCKS5 disallowed";
             case result_code::auth_method_rejected:       return "SOCKS5 no accepted authentication method";
             case result_code::network_unreachable:        return "SOCKS5 network unreachable";
             case result_code::host_unreachable:           return "SOCKS5 host unreachable";
             case result_code::connection_refused:         return "SOCKS5 connection refused";
             case result_code::ttl_expired:                return "SOCKS5 TTL expired";
             case result_code::command_not_supported:      return "SOCKS5 command not supported";
             case result_code::address_type_not_supported: return "SOCKS5 address type not supported";
             case result_code::failed:                     return "SOCKS5 general unexpected failure";
             default:                                      return "unknown error";
             }
           }
           error_condition
           default_error_condition(int ev) const noexcept override {
               return error_condition{ev, *this};
           }
           bool equivalent(int ev, error_condition const& condition)
               const noexcept override {
               return condition.value() == ev && &condition.category() == this;
           }
           bool equivalent(error_code const& error,
                           int ev) const noexcept override {
               return error.value() == ev && &error.category() == this;
           }
         } const static instance;
         return instance;
       }

       error_code make_error_code(result_code se) {
           return error_code{
               static_cast<std::underlying_type<result_code>::type>(se),
               get_result_category()};
       }
   } // namespace socks5

   template <>
   struct boost::system::is_error_code_enum<socks5::result_code>
       : std::true_type {};

   namespace socks5 {
       using namespace std::placeholders;

       template <typename Proto> struct core_t {
           using Endpoint = typename Proto::endpoint;
           using Query    = typename boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<Proto>::query;
           Endpoint _proxy;

           core_t(Query const& target, Endpoint proxy)
               : _proxy(proxy)
               , _request(target)
           {
           }
           core_t(Endpoint const& target, Endpoint proxy)
               : _proxy(proxy)
               , _request(target)
           {
           }

   #pragma pack(push)
   #pragma pack(1)
           enum class addr_type : uint8_t { IPv4 = 0x01, Domain = 0x03, IPv6 = 0x04 };
           enum class auth_method : uint8_t {
               none   = 0x00, // No authentication
               gssapi = 0x01, // GSSAPI (RFC 1961
               basic  = 0x02, // Username/password (RFC 1929)
               // 0x03–0x7F methods assigned by IANA[11]
               challenge_handshake = 0x03, // Challenge-Handshake Authentication Protocol
               challenge_response = 0x05,  // Challenge-Response Authentication Method
               ssl  = 0x06, // Secure Sockets Layer
               nds  = 0x07, // NDS Authentication
               maf  = 0x08, // Multi-Authentication Framework
               json = 0x09, // JSON Parameter Block
           };
           enum class version : uint8_t {
               none   = 0x00,
               socks4 = 0x04,
               socks5 = 0x05,
           };
           enum class proxy_command : uint8_t {
               connect       = 0x01,
               bind          = 0x02,
               udp_associate = 0x03,
           };
           enum class proxy_reply : uint8_t {
               succeeded                  = 0x00,
               general_failure            = 0x01,
               disallowed                 = 0x02,
               network_unreachable        = 0x03,
               host_unreachable           = 0x04,
               connection_refused         = 0x05,
               ttl_expired                = 0x06,
               command_not_supported      = 0x07,
               address_type_not_supported = 0x08,
           };

           using ipv4_octets = boost::asio::ip::address_v4::bytes_type;
           using ipv6_octets = boost::asio::ip::address_v6::bytes_type;
           using net_short   = boost::endian::big_uint16_t;

           struct {
               version     ver       = version::socks5;
               uint8_t     nmethods  = 0x01;
               auth_method method[1] = {auth_method::none};
           } _greeting;

           struct {
               version reply_version;
               uint8_t cauth;
           } _greeting_response;

           struct wire_address {
               addr_type type{};
               union {
                   ipv4_octets              ipv4;
                   ipv6_octets              ipv6;
                   std::array<uint8_t, 256> domain{0}; // length prefixed
               } payload;

               size_t var_length() const {
                   return sizeof(type) + payload_length();
               }

               size_t payload_length() const
               {
                   switch (type) {
                   case addr_type::IPv4: return sizeof(payload.ipv4);
                   case addr_type::IPv6: return sizeof(payload.ipv6);
                   case addr_type::Domain:
                       assert(payload.domain[0] < payload.domain.max_size());
                       return 1 + payload.domain[0];
                   }
                   return 0;
               }
           };

           struct request_t {
               version       ver      = version::socks5;
               proxy_command cmd      = proxy_command::connect;
               uint8_t       reserved = 0;
               wire_address  var_address;
               net_short     port;

               // constructors
               request_t(Endpoint const& ep) : port(ep.port())
               {
                   auto& addr = ep.address();
                   if (addr.is_v4()) {
                       var_address.type         = addr_type::IPv4;
                       var_address.payload.ipv4 = addr.to_v4().to_bytes();
                   } else {
                       var_address.type         = addr_type::IPv6;
                       var_address.payload.ipv6 = addr.to_v6().to_bytes();
                   }
               }

               request_t(Query const& q) : port(std::stoi(q.service_name())) {
                   std::string const domain = q.host_name();
                   var_address.type         = addr_type::Domain;

                   auto len = std::min(var_address.payload.domain.max_size() - 1,
                                       domain.length());
                   assert(len == domain.length() || "domain truncated");
                   var_address.payload.domain[0] = len;
                   std::copy_n(domain.data(), len,
                               var_address.payload.domain.data() + 1);
               }

               auto buffers() const {
                   return std::array {
                       boost::asio::buffer(this, offsetof(request_t, var_address)),
                       boost::asio::buffer(&var_address, var_address.var_length()),
                       boost::asio::buffer(&port, sizeof(port)),
                   };
               }
           } _request;

           struct response_t {
               version      reply_version;
               proxy_reply  reply;
               uint8_t      reserved = 0x0;
               wire_address var_address {addr_type::IPv4};
               net_short    port;

               auto head_buffers() {
                   return std::array{
                       boost::asio::buffer(this, offsetof(response_t, var_address) + sizeof(addr_type)),
                   };
               }

               auto tail_buffers() { // depends on head_buffers being correctly received!
                   return std::array{
                       boost::asio::buffer(&var_address.payload, var_address.payload_length()),
                       boost::asio::buffer(&port, sizeof(port)),
                   };
               }
           } _response;
   #pragma pack(pop)

           using const_buffer   = boost::asio::const_buffer;
           using mutable_buffer = boost::asio::mutable_buffer;

           auto greeting_buffers() const {
               return boost::asio::buffer(&_greeting, sizeof(_greeting));
           }

           auto greeting_response_buffers() {
               return boost::asio::buffer(&_greeting_response, sizeof(_greeting_response));
           }

           auto request_buffers() const { return _request.buffers(); }
           auto response_head_buffers() { return _response.head_buffers(); }
           auto response_tail_buffers() { return _response.tail_buffers(); }

           error_code get_greeting_result(error_code ec = {}) const {
               if (ec)
                   return ec;
               if (_greeting_response.reply_version != version::socks5)
                   return result_code::invalid_version;

               if (_greeting_response.cauth != 0) {
                   return result_code::auth_method_rejected;
               }

               return result_code::ok;
           }

           error_code get_result(error_code ec = {}) const {
               if (ec)
                   return ec;
               if (_response.reply_version != version::socks5)
                   return result_code::invalid_version;

               switch (_response.reply) {
               case proxy_reply::succeeded:                  return result_code::ok;
               case proxy_reply::disallowed:                 return result_code::disallowed;
               case proxy_reply::network_unreachable:        return result_code::network_unreachable;
               case proxy_reply::host_unreachable:           return result_code::host_unreachable;
               case proxy_reply::connection_refused:         return result_code::connection_refused;
               case proxy_reply::ttl_expired:                return result_code::ttl_expired;
               case proxy_reply::command_not_supported:      return result_code::command_not_supported;
               case proxy_reply::address_type_not_supported: return result_code::address_type_not_supported;
               case proxy_reply::general_failure: break;
               }
               return result_code::failed;
           };

       };

       template <typename Socket, typename Completion>
       struct async_proxy_connect_op {
           using Proto         = typename Socket::protocol_type;
           using Endpoint      = typename Proto::endpoint;
           using executor_type = typename Socket::executor_type;
           auto get_executor() { return _socket.get_executor(); }

         private:
           core_t<Proto> _core;
           Socket&       _socket;
           Completion    _handler;

         public:
           template <typename EndpointOrQuery>
           async_proxy_connect_op(Completion handler, Socket& s,
                                  EndpointOrQuery target, Endpoint proxy)
               : _core(target, proxy)
               , _socket(s)
               , _handler(std::move(handler))
           {
           }

           using Self = std::unique_ptr<async_proxy_connect_op>;
           void init(Self&& self) { operator()(self, INIT{}); }

         private:
           // states
           struct INIT{};
           struct CONNECT{};
           struct GREETING_SENT{};
           struct ONGREETING_RESPONSE{};
           struct REQUEST_SENT{};
           struct ON_RESPONSE_HEAD{};
           struct ON_RESPONSE_TAIL{};

           struct Binder {
               Self _self;
               template <typename... Args>
               decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) {
                   return (*_self)(_self, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
               }
           };

           void operator()(Self& self, INIT) {
               _socket.async_connect(_core._proxy,
                  std::bind(Binder{std::move(self)}, CONNECT{}, _1));
           }

           void operator()(Self& self, CONNECT, error_code ec) {
               if (ec) return _handler(ec);
               boost::asio::async_write(
                   _socket,
                   _core.greeting_buffers(),
                   std::bind(Binder{std::move(self)}, GREETING_SENT{}, _1, _2));
           }

           void operator()(Self& self, GREETING_SENT, error_code ec, size_t xfer) {
               if (ec) return _handler(ec);
               auto buf = _core.greeting_response_buffers();
               boost::asio::async_read(
                   _socket, buf, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(buffer_size(buf)),
                   std::bind(Binder{std::move(self)}, ONGREETING_RESPONSE{}, _1, _2));
           }

           void operator()(Self& self, ONGREETING_RESPONSE, error_code ec, size_t xfer) {
               ec = _core.get_greeting_result(ec);
               if (ec) return _handler(ec);

               boost::asio::async_write(
                   _socket, _core.request_buffers(),
                   std::bind(Binder{std::move(self)}, REQUEST_SENT{}, _1, _2));
           }

           void operator()(Self& self, REQUEST_SENT, error_code ec, size_t xfer) {
               if (ec) return _handler(ec);
               auto buf = _core.response_head_buffers();
               boost::asio::async_read(
                   _socket, buf, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(buffer_size(buf)),
                   std::bind(Binder{std::move(self)}, ON_RESPONSE_HEAD{}, _1, _2));
           }

           void operator()(Self& self, ON_RESPONSE_HEAD, error_code ec, size_t xfer) {
               if (ec) return _handler(ec);
               auto buf = _core.response_tail_buffers();
               boost::asio::async_read(
                   _socket, buf, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(buffer_size(buf)),
                   std::bind(Binder{std::move(self)}, ON_RESPONSE_TAIL{}, _1, _2));
           }

           void operator()(Self& self, ON_RESPONSE_TAIL, error_code ec, size_t xfer) {
               _handler(_core.get_result(ec));
           }
       };

       template <typename Socket, typename EndpointOrQuery,
                 typename Endpoint = typename Socket::protocol_type::endpoint>
       error_code proxy_connect(Socket& s, EndpointOrQuery target, Endpoint proxy,
                                error_code& ec)
       {
           core_t<typename Socket::protocol_type> core(target, proxy);
           ec.clear();

           s.connect(core._proxy, ec);

           if (!ec)
               boost::asio::write(s, core.greeting_buffers(), ec);

           using boost::asio::transfer_exactly;
           if (!ec) {
               auto buf = core.greeting_response_buffers();
               boost::asio::read(s, buf, transfer_exactly(buffer_size(buf)), ec);
           }
           ec = core.get_greeting_result(ec);

           if (!ec) {
               boost::asio::write(s, core.request_buffers(), ec);
           }

           if (!ec) {
               auto buf = core.response_head_buffers();
               boost::asio::read(s, buf, transfer_exactly(buffer_size(buf)), ec);
           }
           if (!ec) {
               auto buf = core.response_tail_buffers();
               boost::asio::read(s, buf, transfer_exactly(buffer_size(buf)), ec);
           }

           return ec = core.get_result(ec);
       }

       template <typename Socket, typename EndpointOrQuery,
                 typename Endpoint = typename Socket::protocol_type::endpoint>
       void proxy_connect(Socket& s, EndpointOrQuery target, Endpoint proxy)
       {
           error_code ec;
           if (proxy_connect(s, target, proxy, ec))
               throw system_error(ec);
       }

       template <typename Socket, typename Token, typename EndpointOrQuery,
                 typename Endpoint = typename Socket::protocol_type::endpoint>
       auto async_proxy_connect(Socket& s, EndpointOrQuery target, Endpoint proxy,
                                Token&& token)
       {
           using Result = asio::async_result<std::decay_t<Token>, void(error_code)>;
           using Completion = typename Result::completion_handler_type;

           Completion completion(std::forward<Token>(token));
           Result     result(completion);

           using Op = async_proxy_connect_op<Socket, Completion>;
           // make an owning self ptr, to serve a unique async chain
           auto self = std::make_unique<Op>(completion, s, target, proxy);
           self->init(std::move(self));
           return result.get();
       }
   } // namespace socks5
  ```
- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   #include "socks5.hpp"
   ///////////
   #include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
   #include <boost/beast.hpp>
   #include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
   #include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
   #include <iostream>

   namespace ba   = boost::asio;
   namespace http = boost::beast::http;
   namespace ssl  = boost::asio::ssl;
   using namespace std::chrono_literals;
   using ba::ip::tcp;

   static constexpr auto connection_timeout = 1s;

   int main()
   {
       auto ios = boost::make_shared<ba::io_context>();

       auto ssl_ctx =
           boost::make_shared<ssl::context>(ssl::context_base::method::sslv23);
       ssl_ctx->set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
       //ssl_ctx->add_certificate_authority(ba::buffer(certs.data(), certs.size()));
       ssl_ctx->set_default_verify_paths(); // FOR DEMO

       auto ssl_socket =
           boost::make_shared<ssl::stream<tcp::socket>>(*ios, *ssl_ctx);

       auto& socket = ssl_socket->next_layer();

       tcp::resolver::query target("example.com", "443");

   #if 1
       std::future<void> conn_result = socks5::async_proxy_connect(
           socket, target, tcp::endpoint{{}, 1080}, ba::use_future);

       std::thread th([ios] { ios->run(); });

       if (conn_result.wait_for(connection_timeout) ==
               std::future_status::timeout) {
           socket.cancel();
           // no need to throw, `conn_result.get()` will give operation_aborted
       }

       conn_result.get(); // may throw error
   #else // synchronously as well:
       socks5::proxy_connect(socket, target, tcp::endpoint{{}, 1080});
   #endif

       socket.set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));

       ssl_socket->handshake(ssl::stream_base::handshake_type::client);

       {
           http::request<http::empty_body> req(http::verb::get, "/", 11);
           req.set(http::field::host, "example.com");
           req.prepare_payload();

           http::write(*ssl_socket, req);
       }
       {
           http::response<http::string_body> res;
           boost::beast::flat_buffer buf;
           http::read(*ssl_socket, buf, res);

           std::cout << res;
       }

       th.join();
   }
  ```

Which on my system tests correctly with an `ssh` SOCKS server:

[image]

Comment: Decided to publish the code for socks4.hpp/socks5.hpp on github: https://github.com/sehe/asio-socks45-client

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Will look into it.

Comment: @dojo_user Heh I'm pretty happy. I tested it, of course *but* I was completely prepared for dejection when you found out your server requires authentication or something :) Cheers

Comment: At this moment I don't need authentication but this may change in the future. For complete support need to add user/password support. Hope this is not hard.)

Comment: Nah. It's just more work. In fact I think the Wikipedia page includes the protocol from that separate RFC in its description of socks5

Comment: btw, is there limitation in the code for several simultaneous connections? Tried to create second connection after success with the first one from same program instance and got an error: "Transport endpoint is already connected".

Comment: No restrictions. Perhaps you used the same socket without shutdown/close. I'll probably check for a big later

Comment: Looks like this is proxy server related thing. I tried several addresses from http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/country/all/socks5/ping/all and only some of them worked. Usual error is SOCKS5 connection refused or timed out though host is online(ping ok), port is opened.

Comment: Likely they just have limited access. Running your own is definitely more reliable. I'll see whether I can compare with different servers.

Comment: Could you please add an authorization by login/password support? I'm ready to pay for this. Contact me please in case you are interested. My telegram contact: ikseg