# HTTP requests via proxy with boost beast

Tags: c++, http, boost, proxy, boost-asio

Is it possible to set a proxy when making HTTP requests using Boost Beast?
Using CURL is straighforward. Anyone has done this?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the kind of proxy. There's a socks4 sample in the Asio library distribution (asio/example/cpp{03,11}/socks4).

I've written a socks4 client (sync/async) on here: [socks4 with asynchronous boost::asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67309087/socks4-with-asynchronous-boostasio/67320567#67320567).

More recently I extended that for socks5: [Is there a native support for proxy connection via socks5 for boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69778112/is-there-a-native-support-for-proxy-connection-via-socks5-for-boostasio/69781530#69781530)

Which I also put on github: https://github.com/sehe/asio-socks45-client. I intend to take some time to rework them at least adding basic authentication. They might get added to the Beast libraries.