# How to pass proxy server's username and password in boost::asio::resolver::query

Tags: c++, boost-asio, http-proxy

I am trying to establish connection to authenticated proxy.
I am trying to achieve the Cpp's alternative for the following command in curl.

`curl google.com --proxy http://username:password@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx`

Is there any way to get connected to authenticated proxy server at least using boost::asio.

Following code is used in cpp to try connecting to proxy server.

`boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(remoteServer,                                                   port, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query::numeric_service);`

I tried following - but all failed to connect to host with error - **Host not found (authartive).**

`#1 - boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(xx.xxx.xxx.xx,
3128,
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query::numeric_service);

#2 - boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("http://username:password@xx.xxx.xxx.xx",
3128,
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query::numeric_service);

#3 - boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("username:password@http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx",
3128,
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query::numeric_service);

#4 - boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("username:password@http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/google.com",
3128,
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query::numeric_service);

#5 - boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("username:password@http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:3128/google.com",
88,
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query::numeric_service);
`

Comment: I suppose someone thought the question confuses DNS with proxies which makes this not a programming question (but a networking/HTTP/proxy one). I didn't downvote though, so I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name resolution never uses the proxy.

You resolve the (qualified hostname) of the proxy server, **before** connecting. Then when you connected you send the destination address to the proxy server.

The proxy server does the DNS lookup.

> *The strings you display in the question are URI's, and only used by convention by programs to do the above steps with.*

Asio does **not** come with proxy support builtin. You have to decide on what type of proxy server you want (HTTP, SOCKS4, SOCKS5) and select a suitable client

There's a socks4 sample in the Asio library distribution ([asio/example/cpp{03,11}/socks4](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/tree/develop/example/cpp11/socks4)).

I've written simple clients for SOCKS4, SOCKS5 before on this site:

- [socks4 with asynchronous boost::asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67309087/socks4-with-asynchronous-boostasio/67320567#67320567)
- [Is there a native support for proxy connection via socks5 for boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69778112/is-there-a-native-support-for-proxy-connection-via-socks5-for-boostasio/69781530#69781530)

For HTTP proxies:

- [Boost asio async_read_some and reading whole data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77863099/boost-asio-async-read-some-and-reading-whole-data/77863203#77863203)